# UPDATE with result from INSERT query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing table, `A`, defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.A(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
);
```

This table has 1,000s of existing records.

I now require a new table, `B`, defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.B(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    some_value int NOT NULL
);
```

I need to create a record in `B` for each record in `A` and add a reference from the `A` record to the corresponding `B` record. Firstly, I need to add a new field to table `A` that references table `B` (which necessarily must be nullable with a default value of `NULL`, at this stage):

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.A
ADD b_id int NULL references dbo.B;
```

How can I create the necessary `B` records and update the `A.b_id` field accordingly? I'm looking for something like this:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.A
SET b_id = (INSERT INTO dbo.B(some_value) VALUES(5));
```

such that the value of `b_id` is the `id` field of the newly inserted `B`. (Clearly, this query isn't valid.)

The only solution I can come up with is to write a complex stored procedure using multiple, separate queries. Is there a way to do this with a single query?

Comment: The only thing that springs to mind is a [`CURSOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql), but they're horrible and should be avoided if possible

Comment: Is the option of having `a_id` in the `B` table feasible?  Then you could insert into `B` and then run another query to transfer the value back to `A`... although I appreciate it's not a great solution

Comment: @freefaller That's kind of what I'm doing with the stored procedure I mentioned: creating a temporary table via a `MERGE` that creates `B`s and associates them with `A`s. Then I perform an `UPDATE` on the `A` table to the value of the corresponding `B`. I'd rather not have to modify `B` to reference `A` because `B` is actually used by other tables too.

Comment: How many values do you need to add to `B` and what logic will associate them with `A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*IF* I am understanding correctly, there's no need for a `CURSOR` here. What you could do is a `MERGE` that allows your to `OUTPUT` both columns from the source data and the target:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.A(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
);
GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N))
INSERT INTO dbo.A
SELECT NEWID()
FROM N N1, N N2, N N3;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.B(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    some_value int NOT NULL
);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.A
ADD b_id int NULL references dbo.B;
GO

DECLARE @IDs table (a_id int, b_id int)

MERGE dbo.B B
USING dbo.A A ON B.id = A.b_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (some_value)
    VALUES(RAND() * 1000)
OUTPUT A.id, inserted.id
INTO @IDs;

UPDATE A
SET b_id = I.b_id
FROM dbo.A A
     JOIN @Ids I ON A.id = I.a_id;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.A;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.A;
DROP TABLE dbo.B;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e08c402b9f26c65686c82ca3da41676)

Comment: Yeah. That's what I'm currently doing. Is there no simpler approach?

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't support outputting data from the source data in the `OUTPUT`clause, @FunProg , and although you could use a `CURSOR`, which to some would seem "simpler", it would be far less performant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing (and able) to make a slight adjustment to TableB as well, you can use `OUTPUT` when inserting. I added `a_id` to TableB for my example. Updating b_id back to TableA is a bit redundant as you would now have TableA's ID in TableB for joining.

Here's an example.

```
-- Mock tables.
DECLARE @TableA table ( id int IDENTITY (100,1) PRIMARY KEY, [name] nvarchar(255), b_id int );
DECLARE @TableB table ( id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, a_id int, some_value int );

-- Mock data.
INSERT INTO @TableA ( [name] ) VALUES
    ( 'TableA_1' ), ( 'TableA_2' ), ( 'TableA_3' );

-- Create an OUTPUT table to capture the values inserted into TableB.
DECLARE @out table ( a_id int, b_id int );

INSERT INTO @TableB ( a_id, some_value )
OUTPUT inserted.a_id, inserted.id INTO @out
SELECT
    id AS a_id, 999 AS some_value
FROM @TableA;

-- Update TableA's b_id column.

UPDATE @TableA
SET 
    b_id = o.b_id
FROM @TableA AS a
INNER JOIN @out AS o
    ON a.id = o.a_id;

-- Show updated results.
SELECT * FROM @TableA ORDER BY id;
```

**Returns**

```
+-----+----------+------+
| id  |   name   | b_id |
+-----+----------+------+
| 100 | TableA_1 |    1 |
| 101 | TableA_2 |    2 |
| 102 | TableA_3 |    3 |
+-----+----------+------+
```